# How to Share a VPN connection with other machines on my network

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, routing, remote

I need to share a VPN connection with a remote user. The VPN connection is one that requires the use of a gRas token, only I have the token. Can someone describe to me, or point me in the right direction, how I can allow this remote user access to my network and allow to them connect through to the VPN tunnel established on my regular workstation?

System with the connection is running Windows 7 Ulitmate.
My internet provider is TWC, the modem/routre is an ARRIS TG1672.

Aside from setting up a windows server that supports multiple users to login concurrently, I am a bit lost how to allow a remote user access to my network and then to allow them to rout traffic through the vpn connection established on my workstation.

Comment: Many VPN clients requiring this level of security modify the network stack in a way to make it basically impossible to do what you are asking.  You should be looking to get the that you are  trying to proxy to get a legit connection to the VPN directly.

Comment: hmm.. I would think that this is possible being that I can rdp to my workstation when I am OOO and can connect the vpn and use it as if I were in the office. My partner and I have been using my workstation in this way, I will leave the vpn connected and he will work with it while I am logged off the machine. Are you saying you do not think it is possible to allow multiple users into my home network, logged into the same machine (or not if possilbe), and route traffic through the vpn?

Comment: `I can rdp to my workstation when I am OOO` - So I am confused, it seems to me like you are saying you already have the answer then?  If you can connect from out of your office, then why would it be different for anyone else?

Comment: well, the way we are currently working, only one user can be logged in at a time since concurrent users can not be logged into a windows 7 machine by default. I did find that you can adjust windows settings so multiple users can login, however i dont want the system resources be too tied up. Thats why I am asking if there is some suggestion to instead letting this remote user only onto the network and route there traffic through the vpn established on the system... dioes that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a stream redirection software (google for "rinetd port forwarding").

So what is a stream redirection program!? Let's say you start such a program on your PC with the VPN connection. In the settings of this program you set that all incoming connections on 3389 are forwarded to the specified host inside the VPN LAN.

So a typical redirection entry looks like "192.168.1.190 3388 10.87.5.10 3389" ->
Where **192.168.1.190** is the IP of your PC running the VPN. **3388** is the port on which you will listen for incomming connections. Why 3388 and not 3389? -> because 3389 is most likely in use by your own RDP on you PC. **10.87.5.10** is the PC inside the VPN LAN to which you connect. And finally **3389** is the port to which the stream will be forwarded.

So when you have this setting running with "rinetd" or some other program on your PC with VPN. To connect from another PC you have to provide the following string in RDP for connection -> "192.168.1.190:3388".

We are using such config nearly each day. We have plenty of different VPN connections and like you no possibility to install them at each PC.